# Prove the function is constant on $(0, \infty)$

Tags: functions

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, 0 \lt a \lt b$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow
> \mathbb{R}$ such that: $$f(x^2 +ay) \ge f(x^2 +by), \forall x,y \in
> \mathbb{R} \tag1$$
>
> Prove $f$ is constant on $(0, \infty)$

I don't know how to start, any idea is appreciated.

Playing a little bit with (1) I can get:

For $y \lt 0, x= \sqrt {-y}$ from (1) $f(0) \ge f((b-a)y), \forall y \lt 0$ or, similar, $f(0) \ge f((a-b)y), \forall y \gt 0$ also $f(0) \ge f(y) \forall y \lt 0$

but it doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any hypotheses on $f$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger Nothing more than (1)

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: A local math contest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z, w > 0$ are such that $z/w \in (\frac{a}{b}, \frac{b}{a})$, then

$$ \begin{cases} x^2 = \frac{bz-aw}{b-a} \\ y = \frac{w-z}{b-a} \end{cases} \quad\Rightarrow\quad f(z) = f(x^2+ay) \geq f(x^2+by) = f(w) $$

and switching the role of $z$ and $w$ gives the reverse inequality $f(w) \geq f(z)$. So the inequalities are saturated and we get $f(z) = f(w)$. Now writing $\alpha = b/a$, what we have shown is rephrased as:

$$ \forall s, t \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ |s - t| < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f(\alpha^s) = f(\alpha^t). $$

From here it is easy to deduce that $f(\alpha^s) = f(\alpha^t)$ for *all* $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$, from which the claim follows.

Comment: Maybe $x^2 = \frac{bz-aw}{b-a}$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci, Ah yes, you are right. Fixed!

Comment: Yes, but you need $bz-aw \ge 0$, you cannot switch just like that. Anyway, I think your idea can work somehow.

Comment: @EugenCovaci, That is why I am assuming $z/w \in (a/b, b/a)$. We have both $bz-aw > 0$ and $bw-az>0$.

Comment: This case you cannot get $f$ constant for all (0, \infty), I think. I'm worried about the fact that $z, w$ are not arbitrary.

Comment: @EugenCovaci, That is why we need an extra step as in my answer. My assumption $z/w \in (a/b, b/a)$ tells that, if we let $\alpha = b/a$ and $(z, w) = (\alpha^s, \alpha^t)$, then whenever $s, t$ are real and $|s - t| < 1$ we have $f(\alpha^s) = f(\alpha^t)$. For arbitrary $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$, you can find a natural number $n$ so that $|s-t|/n < 1$. Then letting $s_k = s + (k/n)(t-s)$ shows that $f(\alpha^{s_k}) = f(\alpha^{s_{k+1}})$ for all $k = 0, \cdots, n-1$, from which we obtain $f(\alpha^s) = f(\alpha^{s_0}) = \cdots = f(\alpha^{s_n}) = f(\alpha^t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0<z_1 < z_2$ such that $az_2\leq bz_1$. Then for:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x^2&=\left(z_2-\frac{b}{a}z_1\right)/\left(1-\frac{b}{a}\right)\\
y&=\left( z_1 - x^2\right)/a
\end{cases}
\end{align}
We have: $f(z_1) \geq f(z_2)$. For 
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x^2 &= \left(z_2-\frac{a}{b}z_1\right)/\left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right)\\
y &= \left( z_1 -x^2\right)/b
\end{cases}
\end{align}
We have $f(z_2)\geq f(z_1)$. Hence $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. Since $z_1 $ and $z_2$ were arbitrary we get $f(z)=C$ for all $z>0$.

**Edit.** Take $z_1 =1$ then we know that $$\{C\}=f\left(\bigg[1, \frac ba\bigg]\right)=f\left(\bigg[\frac ba, \frac {b^2}{a^2}\bigg]\right)=....$$ and this gets all numbers in $[1,\infty)$ since $(b/a)^n\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Now take $z_2=1$ then we know that:
\begin{align}
\{C\}= f\left(\bigg[\frac ab,1\bigg]\right)=f\left(\bigg[\frac {a^2}{b^2},\frac ab\bigg]\right)=....
\end{align}
And this gets all numbers in $(0,1]$. This proves the result since $(a/b)^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

I'll leave the small details to you.

Comment: Tried that to but failed at the same thing like you… $z_2 - \frac{a}{b}z_1 \ge 0$ does not necessarily hold. So your $x^2$ in the second case may not exists. Especially you restrict: $az_2 < bz_1$ hence $z_1$ and $z_2$ are NOT arbitrary…

Comment: $z_1, z_2$ are not arbitrary

Comment: mmm Let me think...

Comment: @Gono now you agree?

Comment: @EugenCovaci now you agree?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ for some $x_1<x_2$, then if we set
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{bx_2-ax_1}{b-a}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad y=\frac{x_2-x_1}{a-b}$$
we reach a contradiction. Thus we have that $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ for all $x_1\le x_2$. It then follows that $f(x^2+by)\ge f(x^2+ay)$ when $x,y\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$ and hence
$$f(x^2+ay)=f(x^2+by)\qquad x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$$
At which point the result is fairly easy to derive.

Comment: For $x=\sqrt{\frac{bx_2-ax_1}{b-a}}$ you also need $bx_2-ax_1 \ge 0$

Comment: Which follows from $x_2> x_1$ and $b>a>0$.

Comment: But how about $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$  for $x_1 \gt x_2$?

Comment: We don’t need it because if $b>a$ then it follows that $x^2+by\ge x^2+ay$ when $y\ge 0$.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Since $x^2+by\ge x^2+ay$ we can apply our result for $x_2\ge x_1$, and then the reverse inequality is what is given to us.

Answer (score 1):

Making the change of coordinates $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 1 & b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x^2 \\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y\end{pmatrix}$$  we find that the given condition can be rephrased as
$$ f(X)≥f(Y), \qquad \text{where }X,Y\in\mathbb R, \ bX -aY ≥ 0 $$
where the second condition can be written $ X≥\frac{aY}{b}$. So actually we have $f(X)≥f(Y)$ if either $X≥Y$ or if $Y≥X≥\frac{aY}{b}$. Hence,  we conclude that for any fixed $Y$, we have
$$ f(X) ≥ f(Y) \text{ for all } X\in[\tfrac{aY}{b} ,\infty) $$
and for any fixed $X$,
$$f(X) ≥ f(Y) \text{ for all } Y\in(-\infty ,\tfrac{bX}{a}] $$
Relabelling $X\leftrightarrow Y$ in this second inequality gives us
$$f(X) = f(Y) \text{ for all } X \in [\tfrac{aY}{b}, \tfrac{bY}{a}]$$
By choosing the two-sided sequence of $Y$-points, $n\in\mathbb Z$,
$$Y_n=\frac{a^n}{b^n}\to\begin{cases}\infty, & \text{if }\ n\to -\infty \\ 0, &\text{if }\ n\to \infty\end{cases}$$
we conclude that $f$ is constant on $(0,\infty)$.